# solidity send ether does not work

Tags: contract-development, ether, contract-design, contract-debugging, ico

I am trying to test out this sample code:

```
contract MyContract {


function foo(address a) returns (uint) {

    // send ether with default 21,000 gas
    // likely causes OOG in callee
    a.send(1 ether);

    // send ether with all remaining gas
    // but no success check!
    a.call.value(1 ether)();

    // RECOMMENDED
    // send all remaining gas
    // explicitly handle callee throw
    if(a.call.value(1 ether)()) throw;
    return a.balance;
}
```

Very simple, just send 1 ether to a specific address, then return address balance, however I always get 0 as output meaning the sending failed:

[image]

what's wrong?

Comment: You should send some ether to smart contract before or call foo with some Ethereum. On screen above I see value 0 wei. How can you send Ether if there is any on smart contract account?

Comment: its not 0, it was 100 ether, there were some bug with JS VM, it initialized to be 100 ether, after I clicked foo several times it becomes a very small number close to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is missing is the **payable** modifier.

I tested this pice of code:

```
contract MyContract {

function foo(address a) payable returns (uint) {
   a.call.value(1 ether)();
   return a.balance;
 }
}
```

I deployed it and then run with Value set to 2 (is means 2 Ether) and it works. Here is the output:
[image]

The output is 1 ETH in Wei.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, it works! What does value set to 1 mean here?

Comment: I edited my answer. Value was set to 2, it means send 2 Ether (from my account to my smart contract address).
The main issue here was lack of payable modifier.